# Why does Python's pip reset to version 10.0.1 in every new virtual environment?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, python, pacman, pip

## tl;dr: Why is pip's version reset to 10.0.1 every time I create a new virtual environment and not automatically cloned from my global 18.0 installation?

Every time I create a new virtual environment I'm told that my `pip` is outdated. I run

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

And get the following output:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

Running `pip -V` outside of a virtual environment returns

```
pip 18.0 from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

So the outdated version is only created when I create a new virtual environment.

Is this a feature of python's virtual environment module?

For the record, the command I run to create a new virtual environment is:

```
$ python -m venv <venv>
```

I installed it by running

```
$ pacman -S python python-pip
```

I am running it in Arch and the output of `python -V` is `Python 3.7.0`.

Comment: Never ran `pip install --upgrade pip` outside of a virtual environment. I ran one really long command early on in my current set up (August 1, 20018) that included `sudo pacman -S ... python ipython python-pip ...`

Comment: Also: I have seen this problem on every arch system I've installed: several times in the last 6 months.

Comment: python-pip is [at 18.0-1 in Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/python-pip/); your venv is broken in some way.

Comment: @jaysonwryan: read my update: my python-pip for the system **is** 18.0-1. It's whenever I create a new virtual environment the `venv`'s pip is 10.

Comment: Yes, that is why I am saying that it is the venv that is broken; not Arch.

Comment: @jaysonwryan I see. Why is my venv broken, though? I've never used anything but pacman to install/update it.

Comment: You'd need to provide details of the venv to answer that.

Comment: @jaysonwryan: how? What details? Isn't it a module built into python? Is there a `--version`?

Comment: How you set it up, [python version](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python/Virtual_environment#Python_versions), etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pip` is not reset when you create a new virtual environment. When you create a new virtual environment, `venv` performs a new installation of `pip` and `setuptools` in this environment. Where does the `pip` version come from? When you run `python -m venv`, the installation of `pip` is a responsibility of the module [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#module-ensurepip) which bootstraps a new `pip` installation. You can check what `pip` version is bundled with Python 3.7:

```
$ python3 -c "import ensurepip; print(ensurepip.version())"
10.0.1
```

This is nothing you can update or modify yourself; the module is part of the standard library. When Python 3.7 was released, the latest `pip` was of version 10.0.1, so it was bundled ([related issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue33131)). Version 18 was released later. Next time, it will be probably updated in the next Python release (3.7.1).

#### Alternative: using `virtualenv`

If you want the latest `pip` to be installed in a fresh virtual environment, you can switch to `virtualenv`:

```
$ pip install --user virtualenv
```

or install system wide using `pacman`:

```
$ pacman -S python-virtualenv
```

`virtualenv` is updated more often than Python, so the latest version installs the latest packages. Usage example:

```
$ virtualenv myenv --python=python3 --quiet
$ source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv) $ pip --version
pip 18.0 from /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: Other than being up to date, is there any other benefit to `python-virtualenv`? I am not overly bothered by the fact that I have to update `pip` in a new `venv`, I was just incredibly curious about why.

Comment: To me, this is more a matter of personal preferences. `venv` is more or less the `virtualenv`, but without all the hacks `virtualenv` has to use due to not being a part of the stdlib. So you can say `venv` is more stable and reliable.

Comment: However, `virtualenv` is an old and mature project, being available for both Python 2 and 3 and having many handy tools evolved around it in all the years. To name a few: `virtualenvwrapper` which simplifies organizing and handling of local virtual environments. This is the tool I use in daily work most of the time. `pipenv`, sort of a pendant of `npm`/`yarn` in the Python world. `tox`, a must-have tool for tests automation in different environments/ for different Python versions. All of them require `virtualenv` as the core dependency in the first place.

Comment: Reagrding: **"Next time, it will be probably updated in the next Python release (3.7.1)."** It hasn't been updated.